# How to mark Scenario Outline as a known defect?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I'm using Cucumber and wanted to mark scenarios with known Jira issues.
I found that we have a tags applied on feature, scenario and examples levels, but don't know how to mark specific scenario under Examples.

```
@feature_level_tag
Feature: Test fearure

  @scenario_level_tag
  Scenario Outline: Test scenario
    When <user> created with name <name>
    
    @example_level_tag
    Examples:
      | user  | name |
      | test  | test |
      | admin | test |
```

How to mark, for example, only admin scenario with some specific `@tag`?

The only way that I found is to have several Examples with different tags, but it's a bad workaround if you have a lot of scenarios with different known defect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as a separate examples table with a tag for the defect:

```
@feature_level_tag
Feature: Test fearure

  @scenario_level_tag
  Scenario Outline: Test scenario
    When <user> created with name <name>
    
    @example_level_tag
    Examples:
      | user  | name |
      | test  | test |
      | admin | test |

    @defect123
    Examples:
      | admin | test |
```